# How can I import a module from another package while keeping the relative imports among modules within that package

Tags: python, import

I have a file structure like this:

```
- my_app
  - package_a
    - module_a
      - from package_b import module_b
  - package_b
    - module_b
      - import module_bb
    - module_bb
```

I want to import `module_b` in `module_a`.

However, inside `module_b`, `module_bb` is imported using `import module_bb`. This is fine when I work under `package_b` because they are from the same package. But if I want to import `module_b` from `package_a`, I have to change the `import module_bb` in `module_b` to `import package_b.module_bb`.

The issue is that the actual `package_b` is quite big and complex and there are many dependencies among modules. I don't want to modify every single import for this to work.

Is there a way to do this? Thank you very much!

I tried packaging `package_b` using `setup.py`. This didn't work and ask me to change all the imports within `package_b` to 'package_b.xxx'.

I also tried `sys.path.insert(1, module_path of package_b)`. This one worked but I am trying to see if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative import in this case. Change `import module_bb` to `from . import module_bb`.